# UNITY creating blendshape from script problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've made a script that converts Meshes into **SkinnedMeshRenderer**, and creates a **BlendShape** for it.

**Depending on all the debug information within the editor, everything looks correct!**

But when i move the BlendShape slider, wrong vertices are moved.

here:

**GREEN** - current position of vertices.

**MAGENTA** - path of each vertex from initial position to delta position.

**BLUE** - position of each vertex in it's final delta position.

**RED** - position of each vertex that are not within the _selection bounds. stay equal to Vector3.zero.

[image: https://forum.unity.com/attachments/blendshapebug-jpg.559830/]

BUT, when i try to see the blend shape in action, i get this:
[image]

When i try the same script, but just moving the vertices to their deltas, it also looks OKAY:
[image]

my question is simple.
**WHAT am i doing wrong in the process of making a new BlendShape** data for the mesh??

here is my c# code:

```c#
private void AddMorph(GameObject _ref, GameObject selection_mesh) {
    Mesh _m = new Mesh();

    // _selection - Bounds for selecting group of vertices within.
    _selection = new Bounds(selection_mesh.transform.position, selection_mesh.transform.localScale);

    // movement delta for future group of vertices.
    Vector3 newDelta = new Vector3(0, -0.4f, 0);

    // name for the future blend shape.
    string MorphName = "Custom[50-250]";

    //
    // Convert Mesh Renderer to Skinned Mesh Renderer, and create and instance of the shared mesh.
    //
    if (_ref.GetComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > () == null && _ref.GetComponent < MeshRenderer > () != null) {
        _m = Instantiate(_ref.GetComponent < MeshFilter > ().sharedMesh);
        Destroy(_ref.GetComponent < MeshRenderer > ());
        Destroy(_ref.GetComponent < MeshFilter > ());
        _ref.AddComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > ();
        _ref.GetComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > ().sharedMesh = _m;
    }
    else if (_ref.GetComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > () != null) // Create instance of shared mesh.
    {
        _m = Instantiate(_ref.GetComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > ().sharedMesh);
        _ref.GetComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > ().sharedMesh = _m;
    }
    else return; // if object has no renderer at all, stop the script execution.

    // Assign the new mesh we instantiated before.
    _ref.GetComponent < SkinnedMeshRenderer > ().sharedMesh = _m;
    // create array with deltas.
    Vector3[] newVertexDeltas = new Vector3[_m.vertices.Length];

    for (int y = 0; y < newVertexDeltas.Length; y++) {
        if (_selection.Contains(_ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y]))) {
            // each vertex found within the _selection bounds, gets the delta.
            newVertexDeltas[y] = newDelta;

            //GREEN draw line - current position of vertices.
            Debug.DrawLine(
            _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y]), _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y] + _m.normals[y] * 0.05f), Color.green, 1000000.0f);

            //MAGENTA draw line - path of each vertex from initial position to delta position.
            Debug.DrawLine(
            _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y]), _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y] + newDelta), Color.magenta, 1000000.0f);

            //BLUE draw line - position of each vertex in it's delta position.
            Debug.DrawLine(
            _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y] + newDelta), _ref.transform.TransformPoint((_m.vertices[y] - _m.normals[y] * 0.05f) + newDelta), Color.blue, 1000000.0f);
        }
        else {
            //RED draw line - position of each vertex that are not within the _selection bounds.
            newVertexDeltas[y] = Vector3.zero;
            Debug.DrawLine(
            _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y]), _ref.transform.TransformPoint(_m.vertices[y] - _m.normals[y] * 0.05f), Color.red, 1000000.0f);
        }
    }

    // Create the new blendshape with vertecies deltas.
    _m.AddBlendShapeFrame(MorphName, 100f, newVertexDeltas, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed.**
Just executed Normals and Tangets recalculation right after adding the new BlendShape.
everything works great now.

```c#
}

    // Create the new blendshape with vertecies deltas.
    _m.AddBlendShapeFrame(MorphName, 100f, newVertexDeltas, null, null);        
    _m.RecalculateNormals();
    _m.RecalculateTangents();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same behaviour (with Khronos Unity GLTF plugin).

Indeed, using `RecalculateNormals` fixes the issue.

We also can use `UploadMeshData(<true/false>)` to update the mesh.

But I still don't exactly understand why ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a blendshape to a skinned mesh renderer using source and target worked for me like this.  Note that all you have to do is subtract the source verts from the target verts to create the delta array.  Then recalculate the normals and tangents.

```html
using UnityEngine;

public class BlendShape : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer source;
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer target;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3[] verts = new Vector3[target.sharedMesh.vertexCount];

        source.sharedMesh.ClearBlendShapes();
        target.sharedMesh.ClearBlendShapes();

        // Calculate delta verts from source to target
        for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++)
            verts[i] = target.sharedMesh.vertices[i] - source.sharedMesh.vertices[i];

        source.sharedMesh.AddBlendShapeFrame("test", 1, verts, null, null);

        source.sharedMesh.RecalculateNormals();
        source.sharedMesh.RecalculateTangents();
    }
}
```